# auto invoice in magento 1.9.2 using paypal

Tags: magento, paypal

we need to disable the auto invoice created by magento after a paypal payment.
The magento version is 1.9.2 and no settings are present to avoid this.
Is there any paypal account setting to stop the auto invoice in magento 1.9.2 ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and I couldn't find an option within Magento to disable that.
However, there are some modules available it seems that will allow you to prevent that auto invoice feature: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/disable-automatic-generation-of-invoice.html

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply, the plugin you mentioned is not working on 1.9.2 version